# Where is this artifact in the output before each epoch coming from during training?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, jupyter-notebook, conv-neural-network

This is really more for aesthetics, but it's been nagging me. I can't seem to understand where this part of the output in my jupyter notebook is coming from (marked by the red arrow in the image)it shows up before each epoch almost like a stutter.

any hints or solutions would be greatly appreciated.

[image: jupyter notebook output training]

this is an exerpt from my code.

```
for epoch in range(epochs):
    start_time = time.time()
    epochs_left = epochs - epoch
    print('training model over %d epochs... There are %d epochs left...' % (epochs,epochs_left))

    learning_rate = learning_rate_final + (learning_rate_...
    
    train_loss, train_acc = 0, 0
    
    for image_path, label in tqdm(train_list, 'training for epoch %d' % epoch): 
        loss_, acc = train(sess, image_path, label, learning_rate)
        train_loss += loss_
        train_acc += acc
    train_loss, train_acc = train_loss / ...
```

thank you.

Comment: Try using `print('training model over %d epochs... There are %d epochs left...' % (epochs,epochs_left), flush=True)`. That way, the buffer will be flushed before the progress bar is printed.

Comment: perfect. thanks a lot. that was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I wrote in a comment, you can flush the buffer so that the message is printed before the progress bar is printed.

```
print('training model over %d epochs... There are %d epochs left...' % (epochs,epochs_left),
      flush=True)
```

You can also shorten this line using f-strings.

```
print(f"training model over {epochs} epochs... There are {epochs_left} epochs left...",
      flush=True)
```